Why doesn't work PDF file open by PDF.js viewer [with URL]?
I downloaded manually the PDF.js viewer, and it was working perfectly in program XAMPP, but when I uploaded to a web server, it broke down. I uploaded also the web, the build folders and the LICSENSE file several times, but I think the issue isn't there, however in the URL.
This is the URL's code, what I'm using:
<td><a class="hrefborder" href="/web/viewer.html?file=%2Fkotta/<?php echo "{$row["elsokotta"]}"; ?>">Open</a></td>

And this is the specific URL. I would open 'Éneklem A Te Jóságodat - A.pdf' from the 'kotta' folder inside htdocs.
http://example.com/web/viewer.html?file=%2Fkotta/%C3%89neklem%20A%20Te%20J%C3%B3s%C3%A1godat%20-%20A.pdf


Could be a character encoding problem. Your URL parameter appears to be in UTF-8, but maybe that is not the character encoding the file system is actually using. Do you have a working URL to request the PDF directly?

I tried to add default charset to .htaccess file, but it isn't working. Or how can I set the character encoding for the file system in different way? How do you mean 'directly'?

You can not influence what character encoding the server's file system is using, via .htaccess. And by directly, I mean what URL you are using to directly access the PDF, without trying to load it via the PDF.js viewer. A working URL to download that PDF.

Thanks for the clarification, yes I can open it directly, in this case, the URL is this:
http://example.com/kotta/414%20-%20%C3%93.%20j%C3%B6jjetek,%20h%C3%ADvek.pdf
I am sure that the problem with the PDF.js. Can you help where can I set the character encoding? I'm using infinityfree web hoster with a free (sub) domain.

When you inspect the requests using browser dev tools, what request for the PDF is actually being made, when you view http://example.com/web/viewer.html?file=...?

@KJ It has the same effect, it also doesn't work.

@CBroe The console write two error messages:
"Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec." // for file "web/viewer.mjs
And the same one for "build/pdf.mjs".
I uploaded these two files again, but it's still bad.

"I uploaded these two files again, but it's still bad." - that error isn't about the content of the files themselves, but how your webserver delivers them. Yours is currently doing that with the response header Content-Type: text/plain, but in that case browsers will refuse to execute any JavaScript. You need to see to it that you get your server to delivers those with Content-Type: text/javascript
